# Rails nifty layout files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to know what files are generated from this command this `rails g nifty:layout`, because I am using rails 4.2.4 and here nifty is not working properly so i will individually generate those files.

Answer (score 1):

```
rails g nifty:layout
```

Isn't a standard generator but one created as a gem by Ryan Bates.
See for reference: https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators

Included generators are:

> nifty:layout: generates generic layout, stylesheet, and helper files.
>
> nifty:scaffold: generates a controller and optional model/migration.
>
> nifty:config: generates a config YAML file and loader.
>
> nifty:authentication: generates user model with sign up and log in.

Be aware that the last commit for this gem was on Oct 16, 2012, so it might not be compatible with rails 4.

Also for reference you could follow the rails guides and learn how to create/edit your own rails generator: 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html